# Curve the lengths of a rectangle with CSS?

Tags: css

Is it possible to make this shape with CSS? It can't be done with border radius, is there another way to 'bend' a rectangles sides?

[image]

Comment: to my knowledge, not unless you use background images or break it into multiple divs (for each round section)

Comment: There's quite a lot you can do **with** border-radius - see this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9HGzJIcfDE

Comment: can you use a canvas and JS? http://codepen.io/Francext/pen/ojwdJ

Comment: maybe this can help you http://www.webgranth.com/css-borders-create-border-and-shapes-with-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answers, the best way to make your shape perfect is using SVG. However with css3 and the help of pseudolements after and before You may have close shapes.

This one is far from good as I've made the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/632pfbzL/1/)** as a fast example but with time you may get better results:

```
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 50% / 10%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: .1em;
}
div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  bottom: 10%;
  right: -5%;
  left: -5%;
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: 5% / 50%;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: -11px;
    width: 130px;
  height: 120px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 20% / 150%;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any widespread method for constructing shapes like that *with pure css*.

What you could try though is using inline svg:

```
background-image: 
    url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='10' height='10'><linearGradient id='gradient'><stop offset='10%' stop-color='%23F00'/><stop offset='90%' stop-color='%23fcc'/> </linearGradient><rect fill='url(%23gradient)' x='0' y='0' width='100%' height='100%'/></svg>");
```

This is just an example svg, you'll have to model your own. It also accepts base 64:

```
background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8;base64,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) no-repeat;
```

Edit: I created a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pm3czdhj/7/
You could also try looking into the css property `clip-path`.

Answer (score -3):

Do some CSS like this will make the rectangle have curved edges:

```
div {
border: 2px solid;
border-radius: 25px;
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but you may want to re-read the question.  Your answer does not really address the problem

Comment: It serves as an example for how to make a <div> tag to have a curved border.  One that, specifically, has a 25 pixel bend in it.  If you put a rectangular shape of something into that <div>, a button for example, then said button will have four 25 pixel curves in it.

Comment: I do not think 'bends' the rectangle's sides, does it? https://jsfiddle.net/8g1j01gn/  - it only 'curves' the corner which is not what the question is about

Comment: Yes, curving a line is a bend; However, different than curving a side vs curving a corner of a rectangle (side != corner).  In any case, your answer does not even produce a shape close to what the OP needs... Did you even re-read the question?